# error INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android

i am getting this error while i am trying to run my app on my device.

I uninstall my app and it didnt works and everything on my manifest seems ok (for me jeje)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="menu.Activities.MainMenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="menu.Activities.LoginActivity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="menu.Activities.validateInfoActivity"
        android:label="Confirmar información" />

    <service
        android:name="services.notificationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>

    <provider android:name="DataBase.businessCore"
        android:authorities="com.mercasavip.business.core" android:exported="true"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change capital letters to lowcase in your package name.